# Windows 10 docker public ip address for accessing from several containers

Tags: docker

I have a few docker-compose running in the background.
I need to connect from one docker-compose container to another.
So when I run `curl 10.0.0.3:8080` I am able to get an answer as expected. The problem is that each developer in the team has a different IP address that answers to this curl call.

Once again, there are 2 different docker-compose running, and I want to connect from one to another.

How can I make all PCs docker to answer the same IP address? (I want to avoid environment variable).
for example, I want the IP: `10.0.0.3` to be valid in each team member's PC.

is that possible?
Thaks

Answer (score 0):

Using IP's when working with docker is considered a bad practice and I strongly discourage it. If you use docker-compose then just use the service name to refer to a service. This way even if IP's change you will still be able to connect to your services

Each instance of docker-compose runs the services in its own network. You can also define a network (`docker network create xxxxx`) and then configure docker-compose to connect to that network. This way all your services will see each other.

If however you decide to go with using IP's, there is a way to set a fixed ip for your service. Check the section `IPV4_ADDRESS, IPV6_ADDRESS` of the Docker-compose [reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

Comment: These are several different `docker-compose` & `docker run` services, in real life they will communicate via global DNS and not locally. this is why I need a global ip address for the entire docker installation. and not service name.

Comment: Forcing an IP onto developers' machines goes against what docker wants to achieve. I find it best if developers can develop in environments that are as close as possible to "real life". I have a feeling your architecture is forcing you to take decisions that will backfire in the long run. I understand now what you want to achieve but I still disagree with using static/hardcoded IP addresses.